# How superhorizon power spectrum would have looked like if there was no inflation?

Tags: cosmology, causality, cosmological-inflation, correlation-functions, cosmic-microwave-background

As it is well known, one of the main motivations for the idea of inflation is the explanation of superhorizon CMB correlations: we observe the existence of perturbations with sizes larger than the size of the horizon at a time when we observe these perturbations, thus, if we want them to be produced by some casual process, there must have been a time when the comoving horizon was shrinking (i.e. inflation): see picture 1 (taken from [D. Baumann's notes](http://cosmology.amsterdam/lecce-lectures/).)

So my question is: suppose we haven't seen any CMB yet and haven't thought about inflation; what would be the natural expectation for the power spectrum curve, and in particular, in the super-horizon region in the usual Hot Big Bang model?

My guess is that at super-horizon scales we should see something like completely random white noise (see picture 2), and at subhorzon scales whatever happens to this white-noise spectrum after it evolves through usual casual cosmological history. Is it correct?
[image: CMB correlations]
[image: White Noise]

Comment: I have been unable to find a definition of "superhorizon". Can someone help me?

Comment: @Buzz superhorizon simply means lengthscale which is larger than the cosmological horizon at that moment of time.